# C++: binary search compile error

Tags: c++, binary-search

I have the following lines of code:

```
if(std::binary_search(face_verts.begin(), face_verts.end(), left_right_vert[0]) &&
         std::binary_search(face_verts.begin(), face_verts.end(), left_right_vert[1]))
```

And when I compile my code, I get the following errors:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.4/algorithm:62,
                 from R3Mesh.cpp:10:
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_algo.h: In function ‘bool std::binary_search(_FIter, _FIter, const _Tp&) [with _FIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<R3Point*, std::vector<R3Point, std::allocator<R3Point> > >, _Tp = R3Point]’:
R3Mesh.cpp:1335:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_algo.h:2762: error: no match for ‘operator<’ in ‘__val < __i.__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>::operator* [with _Iterator = R3Point*, _Container = std::vector<R3Point, std::allocator<R3Point> >]()’
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_algo.h: In function ‘_FIter std::lower_bound(_FIter, _FIter, const _Tp&) [with _FIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<R3Point*, std::vector<R3Point, std::allocator<R3Point> > >, _Tp = R3Point]’:
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_algo.h:2761:   instantiated from ‘bool std::binary_search(_FIter, _FIter, const _Tp&) [with _FIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<R3Point*, std::vector<R3Point, std::allocator<R3Point> > >, _Tp = R3Point]’
R3Mesh.cpp:1335:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_algo.h:2442: error: no match for ‘operator<’ in ‘__middle.__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>::operator* [with _Iterator = R3Point*, _Container = std::vector<R3Point, std::allocator<R3Point> >]() < __val’
make: *** [R3Mesh.o] Error 1
```

I did `#include <algorithm>` in the beginning of the file and I can't seem to figure out the error. The following are the containers used in the function call:

```
vector <R3Point > face_verts;
vector <R3Point > left_right_vert;
```

Thanks.

Comment: What does the interface for the R3Point class look like?

Comment: What did yo use to sort the `face_verts` sequence?

Comment: I actually didn't sort my vectors - I wasn't aware that the container that I'm running binary search on needs to be sorted. Is there a way I can find out if an element exists in my vector by using some other function maybe? Otherwise, I think implementing my own "search" function may be more efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use `binary_search` you input siquence must be *sorted* in accordance with certain comparison predicate. Later, this very same comparison predicate must be given (explicitly or implicitly) to `binary_search` to be used during searching.

So, the questions you should answer in this case are the following

1. Is the input sequence sorted? If it is not, you can stop right here. `binary_search` cannot be used with unordered sequences.
2. If it is sorted, then what comparison predicate was used to sort it? And how was it passed to the sorting function?

Once you know the comparison predicate and the passing approach, you can do the same with `binary_search`.

Note, that the comparison is not necessarily implemented through the `operator <`, as other answers might suggest. It could be a standalone functor-based comparison predicate, for example. Moreover, the fact that `binary_search` did not pick up the comparison predicate automatically (as would be the case with `operator <`) suggests the "standalone" approach.

Answer (score 3):

In order to use binary search, your items must be comparable. `R3Point` doesn't have built-in comparison, that's the core reason.

Moreover, for using `binary_search` your list must be *already* sorted wrt the comparison operation.

Answer (score 3):

You need to implement an `operator <` for your `R3Point` class. The `binary_search()` function will use this operator to determine how to find the target item.

Answer (score 3):

`std::binary_search` uses a predicate function to compare entries. That's `operator <` by default, so you need to overload this op for `R3Point`.

Keep in mind that the input range must be ordered by this op for `std::binary_search` to work properly (well, that's the nature of a binary search).

See http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/binary_search.html.

Answer (score 0):

If the R3Point is implemented by you, then you can add `operator<` for it.

Otherwise, you must implement a comparison functor, and assign it to `binary_search`.

Remember [the following mark](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/binary_search/):

> Returns `true` if an element in the range `[first,last)` is **equivalent** to value, and `false` otherwise.